# Powershell - Change metadata from the properties of the file based on the name of the file

Tags: powershell

Ok, so here is my question:

I have a file with a name like this: IMG_20191215_201811.jpg

What i want is to take the part of 201811 which represents hour, and put it in the created date of the file metadata. Maybe the whole thing, with the date with all 20191215_201811.

What is the best approach to do this?

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\19\SO_56211626.ps1
$Directory = "C:\TestFolder"

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter *.pdf)){
    if($File.BaseName -match '_(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(_\d)?$'){
        $date_from_file= (Get-Date $Matches[1])

        $file.CreationTime   = $date_from_file
        $file.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file
        $file.LastWriteTime  = $date_from_file
        $file | Select-Object Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime
    }
}
```

Or maybe this?

```
$Directory = $env:TEMP
$DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

# create some test files
$TestFileList = @(
    'FileA_2017-10-15.pdf'
    'FileB_2016-04-08.pdf'
    'FileC_2018-01-30.pdf'
    'FileD_2019-09-09_1.pdf'
    'FileE_2015-05-05_2.pdf'
    )
foreach ($TFL_Item in $TestFileList)
    {
    $Null = New-Item -Path $Directory -Name $TFL_Item -ItemType File -Force
    }

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Directory -Filter '*.pdf' -File
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList) {

    # removed split, added regex match to work with ever-growing list of variant file names
    $Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '_(?<DateString>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'
    $DateString = $Matches.DateString
    $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Null)

    $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file

    # show the resulting datetime info
    '=' * 20
    $CurrentFileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.CreationTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastWriteTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastAccessTime
    }
```

P.S.: I'm newbie at this stuff so don't jump on me as i don't even know what is what and this kind of stuff is very heavy on my brain, otherwise .... i wouldn't have asked you guys :)

Thanks,
Bogdan

P.S.2: Kudos to JadonR

Answer (score 0):

The date format in the name of the file matters.  In your example code, you have two formats:

```
yyyymmdd_hhmmss
```

and

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

Each has to be processed separately, with a different RegEx.  Your original RegEx won't work the way I think you expected it to work, so using sub-strings may be more efficient for you.  Nevertheless, here is code that works with your first example.

```
$Directory="C:\TestFolder"
$Things=Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter "*.jpg"
# I do this because I don't use the "ForEach" statement
$Things=@($Things)
$Regex=[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::new("IMG_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.",[System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::None)
for ($i=0; $i -lt $Things.Count; $i++) {
  $Matches=$RegEx.Matches($Things[$i].Name)
  if ($Matches.Count -gt 0) {
    $CreationDate=Get-Date -Year $Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -Month $Matches[0].Groups[2].Value -Day $Matches[0].Groups[3].Value -Hour $Matches[0].Groups[4].Value -Minute $Matches[0].Groups[5].Value -Second $Matches[0].Groups[6].Value
    $Things[$i].CreationTime=$CreationDate
  }
  else { Write-Warning "Skipped $($Things[$i].Name)" }
}
# Now that you have changed the creation time, you need to reload the directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter "*.jpg" | Select-Object -Property Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score -1):

I found I was needing to update file date/time metadata all the time, so I put my solution in a function:

```
Function SingleItemCopyAttributes
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string]$Source,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [string]$Dest,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
        [system.text.stringbuilder]$ErrorLog=$null
    )

    $S = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Source
    $D = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Dest

    Try
    {
        "CreationTime","LastWriteTime","LastAccessTime" | ForEach { $D.$_ = $S.$_ }
    }
    Catch
    {
        If ($ErrorLog -ne $null)
        {
            $ErrorLog.AppendLine("Error setting attributes for '$Dest' `$S.CreationTime=$($S.CreationTime) `$S.LastWriteTime=$($S.LastWriteTime) `$S.LastAccessTime=$($S.LastAccessTime)") | Out-Null
        }
        Write-Host "Error setting attributes for '$Dest'"
    }
}
```

EDIT: The function is put into a file `SingleItemCopyAttributes.ps1` which I execute to load it into memory.  I also can add that function to the top of my script and then call it below in loop where I first copy the item, and then "copy" the attributes with the function above, like this:

```
$SourceDir = #Define Source Dir here
$DestDir = #Define Dest Dir here
#Don't forget to create $DestDir if you need to with
#mkdir $DestDir
gci $SourceDir | % {
    $sf = $_.FullName
    $df = $_.FullName.Replace($SourceDir,$DestDir)
    copy-item $sf $df 
    SingleItemCopyAttributes $sf $df
}
```

If you want to copy all the files/folders recursively

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: And this function where is to be put? Powershell? Powershell ise? CMD?

Comment: I typically save my functions in files with the same name, and then dot-source them in my profile.ps1.  Good article on how PowerShell handles profiles here - [Dr. Scripto - Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: Sorry to be a potato at this, but, how exactly am i supposed to use that code? I am reading it in the hopes that i understand something, when in reality i feel more like a chimp reading newspaper :))

I know that those codes that i provided, they are going into some folders of some sort in somewhere, look for a file name and then the magic happens ... i suppose, i don't know because when i started to ask questions, some wild moderator come by and deleted my question ... and maybe i will never find out my answer :)) HAHA

Comment: He wasn't even in the discussion to have the right to interfere, no explanation given nothing ... he come by, and with all his all mighty power of moderator deleted my comment :))

Comment: Try this: [How To Make Use Of Functions in PowerShell](https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2015/01/how-to-make-use-of-functions-in-powershell.html)  If this answer helps you, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: Way too much of a gibberish bollocks for my brain. Sorry. Can't compute that :))
I think i need a dictionary for dictionary to decode the first dictionary to be able to decode another dictionary to decode the second ... eh ... you get the point :))
I know what i read, i feel like i understand, but in reality ... i don't :))

Comment: From what i understand, the above "code" is for copying files, not modifing creation time from METADATA of the file ... you know ... that little info when you click on properties of the file => Right Click => Properties => Created: dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss.  That is the little info that i want to change with the help of the FILE NAME.
Take the name of the file name => IMG_20191215_201811.jpg  Do some magick and tricks with powershell and then => Properties: ‎15 ‎December, ‎2019, ‏‎20:18:11  For copying files i use >! Microsoft Rich Tools > RichCopy 4.0, kind of a torrent but for file transfer

Comment: Yes.  I said I used similar things in my copy code.  You said you didn't understand how to use the function.  I posted code to explain how to use the function.  If you look at my code and don't understand how to make it copy just the attributes by changing one line, then I think you're looking for someone to write your code for you instead of someone to help you learn how to do it yourself, and that is not what SO is about.